# Need someone to show me how the Zeta function is equal to Euler's product formula?

Tags: riemann-zeta, infinite-product, euler-product

$\zeta(x)$=$1+\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{3^x}+\frac{1}{4^x}+\frac{1}{5^x}+\frac{1}{6^x}+\cdots$
Euler's product formula states, for all $x$ greater than $1$ we have:
$\zeta(x)$=$1\over 1-\frac{1}{2^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{3^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{5^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{7^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{11^x}$$\times \cdots$
The right hand side of the equation is an infinite product of the form $1\over 1-\frac{1}{p^x}$ where $p$ runs through all prime numbers. Also the author states that if we think of the infinite product as a limit, it will get closer to the limit value and that is the Zeta function itself. 
 Can someone show me a proof of this: 
$\zeta(x)$=$1\over 1-\frac{1}{2^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{3^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{5^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{7^x}$$\times$$1\over 1-\frac{1}{11^x}$$\times \cdots$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: Mathologer also has done his own communication of it on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFwSIdLSosI

Comment: Let $A_k$ be the set of integers ($\ge 1$)  whose prime factors are $\le k$. Then $$\sum_{n \in A_k} n^{-s} = \prod_{p \le k} (1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty (p^r)^{-s})= \prod_{p \le k} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$ Is it clear to you ? Therefore $|\zeta(s)- \prod_{p \le k} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}| = ??$

Comment: @reuns not quite but I can see there is some connection though.

Comment: Expand the finite product $\prod_{p \le k} (1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty (p^r)^{-s})$. If $n = \prod_i p_i^{r_i}$ then what will be the coefficient of $n^{-s}$ ?